# How to append two data frame in pandas with both data frame column names

Tags: python, pandas, append, xlsx

df1 =

```
date    column1 column2 column3 column4
1       123     124     125     126
2       23       24     25      26
3       42       43     44      45
```

df2 =

```
date    c_xyz1  c_xyz2  c_xyz3  
1       123     124     125     
2       23       24     25      
3       42       43     44
```

i need output like

df3 =

```
date    column1 column2 column3 column4
1       123     124     125     126
2       23       24     25      26
3       42       43     44      45

date    c_xyz1  c_xyz2  c_xyz3  
1       123     124     125     
2       23       24     25      
3       42       43     44
```

append df2 with df1 with column names 
df1 have columns 4 and df2 have columns 3 with different names need i need to **append with column names**.

**if it is possible while writing xlsx file then fine.**

Answer (score 1):

im pretty sure you can just

```
df3 = pandas.concat([df1,df2])
```

you might want 
`pandas.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)`

```
import pandas
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3],"B":[2,3,4]})
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({"C":[3,4,5],"D":[4,5,6]})

df3 = pandas.concat([df1,df2])
"""
     A    B    C    D
0  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
1  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
2  3.0  4.0  NaN  NaN
0  NaN  NaN  3.0  4.0
1  NaN  NaN  4.0  5.0
2  NaN  NaN  5.0  6.0
"""


df3_alt = pandas.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
"""
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4  5
2  3  4  5  6
"""
```

you could combine to make a csv that had different columns in the middle I guess

```
with open("out.csv","wb") as f:
     f.write("\n".join([df1.to_csv(),df2.to_csv()])

print("".join([df1.to_csv(), df2.to_csv()]))
"""
,A,B
0,1,2
1,2,3
2,3,4
,C,D
0,3,4
1,4,5
"""
```

here is the excel version ...

```
with pandas.ExcelWriter("out.xlsx") as w:
     df1.to_excel(w)
     df2.to_excel(w,startrow=len(df1)+1)
```

Comment: pd.concat()  merge not append , i need to append df2 below to the df1 with column names

Comment: you cannot change column names in the middle of a dataframe

Comment: that looks alot like df3_alt I think (without seeing newlines)

Comment: i need column df2 below to df1 (not like join)

Comment: then i guess thats your csv option ... you cannot change column names in the middle of a data frame and still have it be a dataframe. ..

Comment: OP need write to excel file

Answer (score 0):

i write into xlsx using

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')   
workbook=writer.book
worksheet=workbook.add_worksheet('Validation')
writer.sheets['Validation'] = worksheet
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Validation',startrow=0 , startcol=0)   
another_df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Validation',startrow=20, startcol=0)
```